# No project template for a ‘WPF Ribbon Application’ in VS 2010 after Microsoft Ribbon for WPF installation

Tags: wpf, installation, ribbon, project-template

I installed Microsoft Ribbon for WPF from the following page:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877

But there is no project template for a ‘WPF Ribbon Application’ in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there way to fix it?